# Google OAuth 2 authorization: got Error redirect_uri_mismatch using ajax p

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-search-console

I already set the Authorized redirect URI on Google API Concole as below show.
[Google console API Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RceEq.png)

I used *localhost:64420/index* to get the code, and send the code to *localhost:64420/Auth* to used ajax post parameter try to get the access token.
Sadly, I got the error message:

```
{error: "redirect_uri_mismatch", error_description: "Bad Request"}
```

Here is the script:

```
        <script>
        var code = code;
        var clientID = client_ID;
        var clientSecret = client_Secret;
        var redirect_uri = "http://localhost:64420/Report.aspx";
        var searchurl = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: searchurl,
            data: { code: code, client_id: clientID, client_secret: clientSecret, redirect_uri: redirect_uri, grant_type: 'authorization_code' },
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: true,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception, errorstr) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                alert(errorstr);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: See:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49527135/gmail-api-oauth2-error-redirect-uri-mismatch/49547871#49547871

Answer (score 0):

The redirect URL in your app and the redirect URL you configure in the API console must be an exact character-for-character match. Remember you can configure multiple redirect URLs in the APi Console, so don't be shy and add all possible variants, eg with both http and https. You should really be using https for a redirect URL and I wouldn't be surprised if a future change disallowed plaintext URLs.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am sure about that both redirect URI are exact character-for-character match, and I tried use https but it still got the same error.