# Gmail API OAuth2 Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: python, redirect, oauth-2.0, gmail-api, google-api-client

I followed this Gmail API Python Quickstart tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

I configured my OAuth client ID in the API console as instructed (see the first image below). However, launching the script opens a browser session that results in the 400 error below.

The redirect URL matches what is registered in the API console.

HOWEVER, the quickstart script opens the following URL:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2... &***redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F*** ...

Manually changing redirect URI to http://localhost:8080 partially fixes the problem as I proceed to the authorization request, but then the response can't get returned to the command prompt.

How can I force the quickstart program to produce a URL that leaves the redirect URI as *http://localhost:8080*?

[image: Google API console]

[image: 400 Error]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The cause of the error you're getting is that the [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample) says:

**d**. Select the Credentials tab, click the Create credentials button and select OAuth client ID.

**e**. Select the application type **Other**, enter the name "Gmail API Quickstart", and click the Create button.

However, looking at what you're doing, you are using **Web Application** instead of **Other**.

When I used the **Other** as client_secret.json, I didn't encounter this problem.

**result**:

> The authentication flow has completed.

No hacks/workaround needed. Just follow instructions :)

Comment: @noogui I've been struggling from quite sometime. This was exactly the issue. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Wonderfull! wasted 2 hours and looking at some 3rd party services until I saw this answer, thanks to a ton man.

Comment: Today following application types are available: Web application, Android, Chrome app, iOS, TVs and Limited Input devices, Desktop app, Universal Windows Platform (UWP). I don't understand which one is for Python scripts?

Comment: @R0byn if you use the TVs & Limited Input Devices option then this will work. It doesn't mandate the redirect_uri registrations like Web Application does.

Comment: If you are building a web application, will anything bad happen to use the TVs option? Is there any way to implement this "correctly" with the Web Application setting?

Comment: @R0byn The `Desktop Client` option will work.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

This is happening because the *uri_redirect* parameter being passed to the Google API server is a percent encoded ASCII string. This can be verified by looking at the URL launched by the script:

```
...redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F...
```

The whole URL gets encoded by the quickstart script in the steps following the execution of this line:

```
credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
```

Stepping through the process with a debugger reveals the URL is eventually encoded with the [urlencode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) method from Python's urllib library. This results in the redirect_uri parameter from the client_secret.json file converting from:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

To

```
http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F
```

When Google receives the OAuth request, it compares the **encoded** uri_redirect parameter against the **un-encoded** one registered in the API console. Since they don't match, a redirect_uri_mismatch is returned.

**Solution**

Ideally, Google should modify the API endpoint to ensure that this parameter is decoded if necessary before comparing it to what's registered in the API console.

An acceptable fix would be if the API console would accept encoded redirect URI entries, but it does not:

[image]

**Workaround** (warning: hacky)

Simply replace the encoded redirect_uri parameter in two places in the oauth2client library:

(1) *update_query_params* function in [_helpers.py](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/master/oauth2client/_helpers.py)

```
...
start = new_query.find("redirect_uri")+13
end = new_query.find("&",start)
new_query2 = new_query[:start] + "http://localhost:8080" + new_query[end:]

new_parts = parts._replace(query=new_query2)
...
```

(2) *step2_exchange* in [client.py](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/master/oauth2client/client.py)

```
...
        body = urllib.parse.urlencode(post_data)
    start = body.find("redirect_uri")+13
    end = body.find("&",start)
    body2 = body[:start] + "http://localhost:8080" + body[end:]

    headers = {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }
    if self.authorization_header is not None:
        headers['Authorization'] = self.authorization_header
    if self.user_agent is not None:
        headers['user-agent'] = self.user_agent

    if http is None:
        http = transport.get_http_object()

    resp, content = transport.request(
        http, self.token_uri, method='POST', body=body2, headers=headers)
...
```

Now everything works.

Comment: I've posted the correct answer to the quickstart. You're using "Web Application" credentials instead of "Other".

Comment: Confirmed :) Thanks for the fix